# changin mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, comments

I get this errors all the time, any help. Thank you.

1-`Undefined variable: db_conx`

and

2- `mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given`

**my code:**

```
include_once("db_conx.php");
require_once ("users.php"); 
class Comments{
public static function getComments( )       
{
    $output = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments order by comment_id desc";
    $query = mysqli_query( $db_conx, $sql );
    if( $query )
    {
        if( mysqli_num_rows( $query ) > 0 )
        {
            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_object( $query ) )
            {
                $output[] = $row;
                }
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }
public static function insert( $comment_txt , $id )
{
    $comment_txt = addslashes( $comment_txt );
    $sql = "insert into comments values( '' , '$comment_txt' , $id )";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    if( $query )
    {
```

.................
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: from where you are getting - $db_conx ??

Comment: `$db_conx` is indeed undefined.

Comment: Do you, guys, read your own code, before posting a question

Comment: In all likihood your db conn is a global you're not including into your functions. Try adding `global $db_conx;` to the top of your functions, see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you do realize your query is in a function and your db connection isn't.
this is what you can do. declare the variable `$db_conx` as `global` in your function

```
include_once("db_conx.php");
require_once ("users.php"); 
class Comments{
public static function getComments( )       
{
    global $db_conx;

    $output = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments order by comment_id desc";
    $query = mysqli_query( $db_conx, $sql );
    ...
```

You can read about the global scope [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp)

Comment: Read about the global scope and never use it

Comment: Thank you mr Kombian, your suggestion was perfect.